# How to export DISPLAY onto another linux host's Xserver

Tags: linux, x11, xserver, x11-forwarding

I use Xming for running Xserver on windows machine and that works just fine.

```
export DISPLAY=<windows_host_IPAddr>:0.0
```

But I want to export display onto another linux host.

```
export DISPLAY=<linux_host_IPAddr>:0.0
```

I am running opensuse and I think Xorg should do the job. But I could not figure out what exactly needs to be done.

If there are any other Xming equivalent packages for linux, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you have to do is to enable remote X sessions on your SuSe box. So, login at the desktop, open a shell, and type:

```
xhost +<IP_address_of_server>
```

Where IP_address_of_server is the address of the machine where you are starting your actual program (so you allow incoming X connections).

However, this is not very secure, so a better option may be to use SSH and X-forwarding. Again, on your SuSe box, open a terminal and type

```
ssh -X <account>@<IP_address_of_server>
```

Then, in the ssh session start your X program without any DISPLAY options, and the output should appear on your local desktop.

In case you have trouble with the -X option, you may try the -Y one, but see the manual page of ssh for details.